# Android SDK having trouble with ADB

Tags: 12.04, android, eclipse, development

So, I installed the Android SDK, Eclipse, and the ADT. Upon firing up Eclipse the first time after setting up the ADT, this error popped up:

```
[2012-05-29 12:11:06 - adb] /home/drsmith/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-05-29 12:11:06 - adb] 'adb version' failed!
/home/drsmith/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-05-29 12:11:06 - adb] Failed to parse the output of 'adb version':
Standard Output was:

Error Output was:
/home/drsmith/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[2012-05-29 12:11:06 - adb] /home/drsmith/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-05-29 12:11:06 - adb] 'adb version' failed!
/home/drsmith/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-05-29 12:11:06 - adb] Failed to parse the output of 'adb version':
Standard Output was:

Error Output was:
/home/drsmith/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not quite sure how this is. Feels weird that there's a missing library there. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. No adb is a pretty big blow as an Android developer. How do I fix?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Android SDK platform tools requires `ia32-libs`, which itself is a big package of libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Below are the [latest instructions from Google](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) on how to install Android SDK library dependencies:

> If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install additional packages first. For Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and above, install the `libncurses5:i386`, `libstdc++6:i386`, and `zlib1g:i386` packages using `apt-get`:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
> ```
>
> For earlier versions of Ubuntu, install the `ia32-libs` package using `apt-get`:
>
> ```
> apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```

Comment: And yes, it includes `libncurses` as well.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. They state it in the set-up guide that's out of date and still says Eclipse isn't in the official repository.

Comment: ia32-libs is no longer supported (in Ubuntu 14.04). The following command helped me: `apt-get install libstdc++6:i386`

Answer (score 32):

You need library ncurses 32 bit version installed in your system

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

In addition to libncurses5, you may require libstdc++6.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

With the command

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

You install a lot of libraries that is not useful to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you so much for de `libncurses5:i386` tip. ia32-libs is not a good solution and screw my whole system

Answer (score 1):

If `libncurses` is not installed then install it and try again.

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```

Comment: Tried apt-get install libncurses. Apt-get didn't see anything in the repository.

Comment: This is probably not the problem...but did you make sure to run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I was having the same problem. I tried adding `ia32libs` and it didn't recognize the repo, and recommended a couple others like `lib32z1`. Neither worked. Then I saw this comment,

You need library ncurses 32 bit version installed in your system

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

In addition to libncurses5, you may require libstdc++6.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

This worked great for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue: http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2011/11/02/how-to-install-googles-android-eclipse-plugin-and-or-adb-on-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Solved my problem. This libraries collection can be useful for a lot of developer's programs also.

Answer (score 0):

For me `adb` was missing regardless of all activities.

Then I noticed useful hint shown in the terminal, which I've tried:

> `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`

After that, `adb` command was installed and now I can install on emulated devices whatever I want.